# Flutter: all Widget should arranged vertically in container

Tags: android, dart, flutter, containers

I want to arrange all items vertically in the container, I have taken in a row and as wells as in column but unable to arrange vertically like `Linear Layout` vertical orientation.

```
void main() {
      runApp(new MaterialApp(
        title: "My Demooo2",
        home: new MyScaffold(),
      ));
    }

class MyBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      height: 90.0,
      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all( 8.0),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[100]),
      child: new Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.adjust), onPressed: null),
          new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.disc_full), onPressed: null),
          new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.scatter_plot), onPressed: null),
          new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.delete_forever), onPressed: null),
          new Text("test")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new MyBar(),
          new Expanded(
              child: new Center(
            child: new Text("My Center"),
          ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What you want to exactly achieve? Which widgets do you want to put in verticle alignment?

Comment: @dhuma i want to arrange all icon vertical like as we do in `LinearLAyout` vertically.

Comment: Remove the height on the `container`, replace `row` with `column`. Try to use `mainAxisAlignment` and `crossAxisAlignment` for aligning to start, end and center. Try to read https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/layout to get a better understanding boxed layouts.

Comment: @ishaan i change the height  and `column` as well but not able to found the soultion

Comment: What do you see after removing height and replacing row with column?

Comment: @ishaan see my updated code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know you exact layout requirement - If i Understood your Question - Try this Code:

```
class MyBar extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
    //  height: 90.0,
      margin: new EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all( 8.0),
      decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.blue[100]),
      child: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.adjust), onPressed: null),
          new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.disc_full), onPressed: null),
          new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.scatter_plot), onPressed: null),
          new IconButton(icon: new Icon(Icons.delete_forever), onPressed: null),
          new Text("test")
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Material(
      child: new Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          new MyBar(),
          new Expanded(
              child: new Center(
                child: new Text("My Center"),
              ))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output:

[image]